# Способ расширения/наследование/декорирования 2D массива

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Существует ли какой-либо способ расширить встроенный прямоугольный массив в c#?
Например:

```
public class Array2D<T>:????
{
    private T[,] _data;

    public Array2D(T[,] vals)
    {
        _data = vals;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Row( int iRow)
    {
        return _data.Cast<T>().Select((t, j) => _data[iRow, j]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Точнее опишите задачу, я ничего не понял. Как сочетается приведенный код с вопросом над ним?

Comment: Андрей, спасибо за чтение моего вопроса. Я имела ввиду расширить или декорировать встроенный двумерный массив c#. В частности, добавить возможность работы со отдельными строками/столбцами. В оригинальном вопросе стояло слово "decorate". Но в этом нет необходимость, т. к. у встроенного **двумерного** массива не так уж много уникальных функций. Легче написать просто новый класс с индексатором.

Comment: Можно использовать [jagged array](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) (массив массивов или "изрезанный"). Там каждая строка - отдельный массив.

Comment: @Irina про поисковик: вы можете использовать https://duckduckgo.com/ и в нём вообще отключить страну в поиске, либо выбрать US или UK. (может и в google.com так можно — я не искал)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использовать [методы расширения](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)?

```
public static class TwoDimensionalArrayExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Row<T>(this T[,] array, int iRow)
    {
        if (array == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
        }
        if (iRow < array.GetLowerBound(0) && iRow > array.GetUpperBound(0))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(iRow));
        }

        for (int columnIndex = array.GetLowerBound(1); columnIndex <= array.GetUpperBound(1); columnIndex++)
        {
            yield return array[iRow, columnIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var array = new int[2, 2] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
    foreach (var value in array.Row(0))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Раз уж используете `GetLowerBound`, то надо использовать и `GetUpperBound`

Comment: @Андрей точно, смешались кони и люди. Поправил, спасибо.

Comment: Спасбо, c# классный!

Comment: @Irina не за что!

Comment: **Што?** Цикл по всем строкам с целью найти нужную строку по номеру? Это юмор такой?..

Comment: Исправил вам код. Пожалуйста, больше не советуйте такое новичкам

Comment: @PavelMayorov что-то и вправду помутнение нашло :). Спасибо.